# Issue when connect .Net app inside a Docker container to remote Mysql Server

Tags: mysql, .net, docker, containers

I have a Mysql database installed on a remote server(IP: 172.17.56.104)(Mysql not containerized). I also have a Selenium project to run test, when the test run, the test result is inserted to database. Everything is working. Now I containerize the Selenium project and run the test using docker-compose, it shows an timeout in connection to database, I guess the code inside the container cannot connect to the remote database. Hopefully somebody can give me a suggestion for this.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 4444

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MyProject/MyProject.csproj", "MyProject/"]
RUN dotnet restore "MyProject/MyProject.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MyProject"
RUN dotnet build "MyProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

ENV CONNECTION_STRING "server=172.17.56.104;Database=dbname;user id=dbusername;password=dbpassword;port=3306"
ENV RERUN_FAILED_COUNT "0"

FROM build AS Test
WORKDIR "/src/MyProject"
CMD ["dotnet", "test"]`
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
    selenium:
      image: selenium/hub
      ports:
        - 4442:4442
        - 4443:4443        
        - 4444:4444
      networks:
        - docker_network  
    chrome:
      image: selenium/node-chrome
      shm_size: 2gb
      depends_on:
        - selenium
      environment:
        - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium
        - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
        - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
        - SE_NODE_OVERRIDE_MAX_SESSIONS=true
        - SE_NODE_MAX_SESSIONS=5
      ports:
        - 5901:5900   
      networks:
        - docker_network
    test:
      image: mytest
      depends_on:
        - selenium
        - chrome
      ports:
        - 4445:4444
      volumes:
        - ./Result:/src/Result
      networks:
        - docker_network
networks: 
    docker_network:
```

In test service, I use port mapping 4445:4444, I guess the traffic would go from the container port 4444 to the port 4445 on my PC and connect to the remote DB. I'm not sure this's correct or not.

When I run docker-compose up, it shows this exception

```
DBConnect:System.TimeoutException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
test-1      |    at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetTcpStream(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings, MyNetworkStream& networkStream)
test-1      |    at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetStream(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings, MyNetworkStream& networkStream)
test-1      |    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
test-1      |    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
test-1      |    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
test-1      |    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()
test-1      |    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
test-1      |    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
test-1      |    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
test-1      |    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to ping some external address like 8.8.8.8 from inside your container, with terminal. If the ping is ok, then the problem is maybe on the side of mysql server. Some ports or something.
And check your docker_network settings, maybe you should use host network, but i don't think so.